# Activate PressAndHold for LibreOffice or OpenOffice

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, internationalization, libreoffice

With most apps on my macos (TextEdit, TextWrangler, Skype, WeChat, Mail, Xcode, Android Studio, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) when I hold down a letter like <kbd>E</kbd>, I get the choice of accents to use from the **PressAndHold** popup:

[image: e]

Alas, when I switch to a powerful document editor like **LibreOffice**, I lose this ability to choose accents.

<sub>Note: Sierra and High Sierra</sub>

Comment: For reference, Microsoft Word for macOS works fine with PressAndHold.

Comment: You have to ask the people who make Libreoffice to incorporate this feature.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not supported by LibreOffice 5.3 according to [this page](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49967).  It's the same for 5.4 according to my tests.  I did not try the dev version 6.0.

---

> EricP 2017-06-01 01:56:19 UTC [Comment 8](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49967#c8)
>
> A few years later now... Press And Hold still does not work in
>   LibreOffice, even though LibreOffice is now built against an SDK
>   requiring MacOS 10.8 or higher (see [comment 3](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49967#c3)).  As indicated in
>   [bug 42437, comment 7](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42437#c7), just an SDK update is not enough; adding this
>   feature will require some developer time.
>
> It is, apparently, possible to "add" Press and Hold support to some
>   applications simply by typing a Terminal command similar to this:
>
> defaults write org.libreoffice ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
>
> but this does NOT enable Press and Hold in LibreOffice 5.3.

Comment: LibreOffice 7.0.3.1 still doesn't allow it.  I also tried `sudo defaults write org.libreoffice ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` in case it had to do with the app being protected.  Nope, still doesn't.