# On macOS, how can you enable repeated keys but only for specific apps?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, ventura

I found out how to disable to the accented character popup for all apps [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/332769/483079) but I like the popup in my web browser and when typing emails but not for instance while using my terminal or IDE.

Is it possible to enable key repeat for some apps but not others or is it an all or nothing setting?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the `-g` defines it as a global, same as `NSGlobalDomain`. There's an outside possibility an app may respond to it instead as a local, e.g https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308104/activate-pressandhold-for-libreoffice-or-openoffice

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152551/how-can-i-disable-applepressandholdenabled-for-a-specific-application-repeat which is way above my paygrade ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command sets the "Global Preference" for the user:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

You can set preferences per-app, with commands such as:

```
defaults write <com.company.app> ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

or:

```
defaults write -app myTerminal ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

These will override the global setting. However:

Whether the app will respond to the preference may depend on the way that the app has been coded; e.g. to what extent it uses and customizes NSTextView.

Comment: thank you so much!